# Reputation box not showing on first hover

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

I was checking my reputation graph and while I **mouseover** it from the right side to check today's bar. It didn't showed the reputation box.

But when I hovered over previous bars and then came back to today's reputation it showed.

Is this default behavior or some bug ?

***This one don't have padding between green bar and division it's contained in.***

[image: Reputation box not showing on hover.]

---

***This one have padding between green bar and division it's contained in. It works fine.***

[image: Reputation box showing on hover.]

I added .gif because that **hand** cursor was not getting captured using <kbd>**PrtSc**</kbd> key.

Comment: What browser? What OS? I could not reproduce this with latest Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Am using Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (Official Build) m (32-bit), Windows 7. There seems to be a special case when this happens. If you notice closely  your graph then sometimes there is no padding between green bar and the division it is embedded in. When there is no padding this happens.

Comment: @Oded: I have added a new case where it works.

Comment: Confirmed with the latest Firefox on Ubuntu (32-bit).